# error of finding size of database in IBM netezza Aginity workbench on win 7

Tags: mysql, sql, database, netezza

I need to find the size of a database in Aginity Workbench for Netezza on win 7.

The SQL does not work for me:

```
   select orx.database::nvarchar(64) as "databasename" ,
        case when sum(sod.used_bytes) is null then 0 else sum(sod.used_bytes)/1073741824 end as "usedspace_gb",
        case when sum(sod.allocated_bytes) is null then 0 else sum(sod.allocated_bytes)/1073741824 end as "allocatedspace_gb"
  from _v_sys_object_dslice_info sod inner join _v_obj_relation_xdb orx on orx.objid = sod.tblid
  group by "databasename"
  order by "databasename";
```

The error is

```
     permission denied on "_V_SYS_OBJECT_DSLICE_INFO".
```

Any

Answer (score 1):

Aginity Workbench will typically list the approximate database size next to name of each database in the object browser window, if you have permission to calculate the value.

In order to calculate the size of the database you need select privileges on _V_SYS_OBJECT_DSLICE_INFO and _V_OBJ_RELATION_XDB with in the database in question. You are not authorized to do what you want.